# Как в QSettings прописать сохранение и загрузку состояния RadioBatton'ов

Tags: qt5

Имеется 4 RadioButton кнопки. Расположены в GroupBox'е. Работают зависимо друг от друга. Каким образом прописать функции загрузки и сохранения настроек, чтобы отмеченная ранее кнопка при запуске программы уже была включена. Для примера привожу отлично работающий код, в котором прописаны настройки для 2-ух CheckBox'ов. Попытка по аналогии с ними прописать RadioButton'ы не увенчалась успехом.

```
void MainWindow::saveSettings()
```

{

```
settings->beginGroup("CheckBoxState");
settings->setValue("CheckBoxState", ui->checkBox->isChecked());
settings->setValue("CheckBoxState_2", ui->checkBox_2->isChecked());
settings->endGroup();

settings->setValue("RadioButton_1", ui->radioButton_1->isChecked());
settings->setValue("RadioButton_2", ui->radioButton_2->isChecked());
settings->setValue("RadioButton_3", ui->radioButton_3->isChecked());
settings->setValue("RadioButton_4", ui->radioButton_4->isChecked());
settings->endGroup();
```

}

void MainWindow::loadSettings()

{

```
settings->beginGroup("CheckBoxState");
ui->checkBox->setChecked(settings->value("CheckBoxState").toBool());
ui->checkBox_2->setChecked(settings->value("CheckBoxState_2").toBool());
settings->endGroup();

settings->beginGroup("RadioButtons");
ui->radioButton_1->setChecked(settings->value("RadioButton_1").toBool());
ui->radioButton_2->setChecked(settings->value("RadioButton_2").toBool());
ui->radioButton_3->setChecked(settings->value("RadioButton_3").toBool());
ui->radioButton_4->setChecked(settings->value("RadioButton_4").toBool());
settings->endGroup();
```

}

Answer (score 2):

В функции void MainWindow::saveSettings(), в группе с RadioButton кнопками, нет строчки, которая открывала бы эту группу: settings->beginGroup("RadioButtons");.
После того как начало группы было обозначено, сохранение состояния кнопок заработало.